# Debugging NuGet Packages - Symbols with Sources not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I'm trying to build out both the nuget packages and symbols for my library. I'm using TeamCity to build the packages, then pushing them to my [internal SymbolSource repo](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2011-04-22/Set_up_your_own_NuGet_gallery_with_SymbolSource).

Everything seems to be building/packaging/pushing fine, but when I go to debug into the my nuget package (using VS2012) the source code is not correct, better yet, I can't find the method names it's showing me anywhere in the library.

My Project Structure:

```
MyProject /
  Bin/
    release/
      MyProject.dll
  VariousFolders/
    CSFiles.cs
  VariousCSFiles.cs
  MyProject.csproj
  MyProject.nuspec
```

In my .nuspec file (Note, the v4.0 and v4.5 directories are handled on TeamCity side):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProject</id>
    <version>0.0</version>
    <title>MyProject</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Possibly You</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Sweet Description</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyProject\**\*.cs" target="src" />
    <file src="MyProject\bin\release\v4.0\*.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="MyProject\bin\release\v4.0\*.pdb" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="MyProject\bin\release\v4.5\*.dll" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="MyProject\bin\release\v4.5\*.pdb" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Inspecting the teamcity produced MyProject.0.0.nupkg

```
lib/
  net40/
    MyProject.dll
  net45/
    MyProject.dll
```

Inspecting the TeamCity produced MyProject.0.0.symbols.nupkg

```
lib/
  net40/
    MyProject.dll
    MyProject.pdb
  net45/
    MyProject.dll
    MyProject.pdb
src/
  VariousFolders/
    CSFiles.cs
  VariousCSFiles.cs
```

So the problem I **assume** is that when I push the package up to my internal symbol repo, I go look at the file structure, it's as follows:

```
Data/
  MyProject/
    0.0/
      Bianaries/
        MyProject/
          some_hash/
            MyProject.dll
            MyProject.pdb
            MyProject.txt
      Sources/
        [Empty]
      MyProject.0.0.nupkg
```

The Sources folder is empty, 100% empty, I can't seem to get any .cs file into that 'Sources' folder, but then again, I don't know what's really going on between the nuget push to my repo, the actual dumping into the data folder and VS2012 magically pulling in the debug symbols.

So, I'm at a complete loss for where to check next.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work. But have you tried resetting the VS2012 settings? You can do that by TOOLS -> Import and Export Settings and in the dialog box select Reset all settings option. You can save the current settings if you want to.

Comment: I have reset the settings and it hasn't done anything. I have pretty much given up on a solution for this. Nuget, C# and VS are on my bad side right now. Basically we have every library, website, API website, and all our console apps in a single git repo. That has been the best solution at the moment. Long story short, never create your own nuget packages.